# Sometimes VIM deindents my line after press <Enter>

Tags: vim

Greeting, since I've been using VIM, sometimes when I enter `<Enter>` to return to the line, the whole previous line gets completely **de-indented**. For example:

```
        // Before entering:
        function helloProcessor() {I'm here}

        // After entering:
function helloProcessor() {
        I'm here
}
```

Currently, my shortcut is :`inoremap { {<CR>}<Esc>0`.

Comment: Hello. With which programming language is this happening?

Comment: @Atalajaka, with PHP especially.